# How to move object instance to another class?

Tags: python, oop

Basically I want to have two classes `Trades` and `HistoricalTrades`. The second  one would be a copy of the first with few more attributes. The `Trades` instances would be deleted after I get copies on `HistoricalTrades`

I have solved this by passing attributes manually.

```
class Trades:
    ...

class HistoricalTrades:
    ...

k = Trades(price=123, amount=10)
h = HistoricalTrades(price=k.price, amount=k.amount, sell_date=k.sell_date)
k.delete()
```

It kinda works as expected but I feel it is not elegant. Is there any other (better) way to move class instance to other class?

Comment: Based on super-limited info, I think you want to look into inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case, assuming no use of `__slots__`, and that the three attributes used are in fact the sole attributes of `Trade`, you could get away with a small cheat, changing:

```
h = HistoricalTrades(price=k.price, amount=k.amount, sell_date=k.sell_date)
```

to:

```
h = HistoricalTrades(**vars(k))
```

[`vars(k)` returns the `__dict__` of `k` itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars), which we then unpack with `**` into the name/value pairs as the keyword arguments to initialize `HistoricalTrades` with.

That solution is a little kludgy (as noted, it depends on not using `__slots__` and not having any other attributes). Really, the nice way to do this is to define an alternate constructor for `HistoricalTrades` that does the slog work for you, simplifying use for the caller:

```
class HistoricalTrades:
    ...
    @classmethod
    def from_trade(cls, trade):
        return cls(price=trade.price, amount=trade.amount, sell_date=trade.sell_date)
```

Yeah, it's the same code, but it's written once, and every call site can simplify to:

```
h = HistoricalTrades.from_trade(k)
```

which is both concise *and* self-documenting.

Comment: Thanks the second method is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance sounds useful here:

```
class Trades:
    ...

class HistoricalTrades(Trades): # This will make HistoricalTrades inherit characteristics from Trades
    ...

h = HistoricalTrades(price=123, amount=10, sell_date="Some data not provided")
```

But I think more information would be needed for us to provide you with a more appropriate answer...